# How to get other columns when using annotate as group by in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, group-by, aggregate-functions

I want to group students of a class and get the max grade along with the name of the student with the max grade.

I want to replicate this SQL query using Django Models:

```
SELECT class_name, MAX(grade), name FROM students ORDER BY grade DESC GROUP BY class_name
```

Using this code, I can get class_name and max(grade) but there seems to be no way to get name.

```
entity.objects.values('class_name').order_by('-grade').annotate(Max('grade'))
```

Apparently this query is wrong according to SQL Server but it is OK with MySQL and it returns name of the first row which is what I want because of the ORDER BY.

Any ideas?

Comment: Surely that's not valid SQL, is it? Whose value for col3 would you get?

Comment: @Daniel It is valid SQL. You get the first row's value for col3 and that is what I want.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. You would get `Column 'col3' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

Comment: @Dan Well it is ok with mysql to say the least and I have a use for it. you can see a similar code here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-max-function.htm